How to fix android Error : Inconsistent JVM-target compatibility detected for tasks 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' (11) and 'compileDebugKotlin' (17)
I am changing the targetSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion from 33 to 34.
For that I changed this:
ddistributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.2-all.zip.

The project got synced successfully but when I am trying to build it it is giving me error : Inconsistent JVM-target compatibility detected for tasks compileDebugJavaWithJavac (11) and compileDebugKotlin (17)
I looked for various solutions where I should do:
sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17

but in my build.gradle, I don't have compileOptions and kotlinOptions.

Just add compileOptions and kotlinOptions to your android scope:
android {
    compileSdk 34
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 34
        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}

And don't forget to set JRE to 17 via Android Studio:
Settings > Build,Excution,Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle -> Gradle JDK
